# What is $\Delta t$ in the time-energy uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In non-relativistic QM, the $\Delta E$ in the time-energy uncertainty principle is the limiting standard deviation of the set of energy measurements of $n$ identically prepared systems as $n$ goes to infinity. What does the $\Delta t$ mean, since $t$ is not even an observable?

Comment: Nice explanation by [Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/uncertainty.html)

Comment: The first paper to rigorously formulate this problem is [Mandelstam and Tamm](http://daarb.narod.ru/mandtamm/mt-eng.pdf).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Let a quantum system with Hamiltonian $H$ be given.  Suppose the system occupies a pure state $|\psi(t)\rangle$ determined by the Hamiltonian evolution.  For any observable $\Omega$ we use the shorthand
$$
  \langle \Omega \rangle = \langle \psi(t)|\Omega|\psi(t)\rangle.  
$$
One can show that (see eq. 3.72 in Griffiths QM)
$$
  \sigma_H\sigma_\Omega\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}\left|\frac{d\langle \Omega\rangle}{dt}\right|
$$
where $\sigma_H$ and $\sigma_\Omega$ are standard deviations
$$
  \sigma_H^2 = \langle H^2\rangle-\langle H\rangle^2, \qquad \sigma_\Omega^2 = \langle \Omega^2\rangle-\langle \Omega\rangle^2
$$
and angled brackets mean expectation in $|\psi(t)\rangle$.  It follows that if we define
$$
  \Delta E = \sigma_H, \qquad \Delta t = \frac{\sigma_\Omega}{|d\langle\Omega\rangle/dt|}
$$
then we obtain the desired uncertainty relation
$$
  \Delta E \Delta t \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}
$$
It remains to interpret the quantity $\Delta t$.  It tells you the approximate amount of time it takes for the expectation value of an observable to change by a standard deviation provided the system is in a pure state.  To see this, note that if $\Delta t$ is small, then in a time $\Delta t$ we have
$$
  |\Delta\langle\Omega\rangle| =\left|\int_t^{t+\Delta t} \frac{d\langle \Omega\rangle}{dt}\,dt\right| \approx \left|\frac{d\langle \Omega\rangle}{dt}\Delta t\right| = \left|\frac{d\langle \Omega\rangle}{dt}\right|\Delta t = \sigma_\Omega
$$

Comment: What happens if the standard deviation of the observable is itself a function of time?then we cannot argue that it is the time taken by the expectation to change by one s.d as s.d is too a function of time.

Comment: @user157588 Sure you can.  There's nothing wrong with $\Delta t$ depending on time.

Comment: @joshphysics But not with your reasoning.

Comment: @Dog_69 How so?

Comment: @joshphysics: Because Griffiths says ''asume that $Q$ does not depend explicitly on $t$'' (p. $113$, 1995 edition).

Comment: Note also in the [John Baez's web page](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/uncertainty.html) appears $$\langle[A,H]\rangle = \frac{d}{dt}\langle A \rangle, $$ which is true if and only if $\langle \partial A/ \partial t\rangle = 0$.

Comment: @Dog_69 The time dependence to which I was referring when I said that there is nothing wrong with $\Delta t$ depending on time is *not* time dependence coming from the observable itself.  It is time-dependence coming from the state evolving according to Schrodinger evolution which leads both its expectation value and standard deviation to depend on time.

Comment: @joshphysics: Oh yes, you're prefectly right. I misunderstood MO comment. I sow time dependence on $A$ and I thought he was asking for $\langle\partial A \partial t \rangle$, but I was wrong. My apologies. _Mea culpa_.

Comment: @Dog_69 Not a problem at all.

Comment: I think you have derived a correct result, but it is not the one people have in mind when they refer to energy-time uncertainty. Rather, the latter is like, and is the result of, frequency-time uncertainty.

Comment: @AndrewSteane I agree from my experience that it seems there is a disconnect between this mathematical result and the common usage of the phrase "energy-time uncertainty principle."  However, I've never delved deeply enough into the literature to be convinced that what people mean by this principle can in general be formalized such that it follows mathematically from Shrodinger evolution.  I've mostly encountered it in a way that it comes off almost as a physical heuristic, but this might be ignorance.  It's reassuring to have a formally correct result to rely on that is easily interpretable.

Comment: I am somewhat unsure of how the definition for the uncertainty in time is well motivated here? How de we justify the form for the variance of the observable $\Omega$?

Comment: @joshphysics I think a better analysis can be done? I mean the uncertainty principles are usually a statement about the measurement. But here you are using the Heisenberg equations of motion (which relies on unitary evolution) ... Further your also integrating but we know the measurement is discontinuous so I'm not sure if that would be an intuitive definition .... Please update your answer in light of my comment

Comment: is the statement that $\Delta t$ is "*the amount of time it takes for the expectation value of an observable to change by a standard deviation provided the system is in a pure state*" accurate though? It is only true as long as the linear approximation you are making holds for the (generally non-infinitesimal) time it takes for $\langle\Omega\rangle$ to change in modulus by $\sigma_\Omega$. Is there a reason to think that this is true in general? In other words, the statement is true *assuming $\partial_t\langle\Omega\rangle$ can be considered as constant* during that time

Comment: @glS Note that you slightly mis-quoted -- "approximate" is missing.  Note also that there is a squiggly equals sign in the computation on the last line acknowledging the linearization you're referring to.

Comment: @joshphysics I can see that it is an approximation. What I'm wondering is whether there is reason to believe that this approximation is justified. If the integral is not close to its linearisation in general (which might very well happen if the time it takes for the expval to change by a standard deviation is not small), then the statement that we can interpret $\Delta t$, even approximately, as you say, might not be tenable. Maybe one can make the argument that the approximation holds under the assumption of $\partial_t\langle\Omega\rangle$ varying sufficiently slowly in time though.

Comment: @glS I agree that you have to be careful about what degree of approximation you're making depending on how rapidly the integrand varies in time.  There's actually a version of this treatment of the time-energy uncertainty principle due to Mandelstam and Tamm that defines $\Delta t$ in a way that no such issues arise in the interpretation -- maybe I'll add that to this post.  In the meantime, you can take a look at it for yourself in their paper.  It's linked in the comments to the original question.

Comment: @joshphysics yes I'm aware of quantum speed limits a la mandelstam and tamm and variations thereof, but I like this way of interpreting the time energy uncertainty relation, I was just curious if there was a way to make this interpretation in all cases/pointing out that you probably cannot

Comment: @joshphysics any idea what the error term involved in the approximation might be?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous That's a great question that I've never considered oddly enough (probably because I've never really used this in practice, but only as a conceptual tool for understanding the implications of quantum mechanics).  I'm curious though now, and if I find something, I'll let you know.  There is a paper that might discuss this called "Mathematical analysis of the Mandelstam–Tamm time-energy uncertainty principle" by Gray and Vogt, but I haven't read it in detail, so I'm not sure at the moment.

Comment: @joshphysics My resources are limited as I'm not currently affiliated with a university "Mathematical analysis of the Mandelstam–Tamm time-energy uncertainty principle." However, this pause enabled me create my own derivation of the uncertainty principle and I've succeeded with something which does enable me talk about time in a "nice" and "insightful" way. Do you know any thermodynamic derivation of this principle? (I have googled but unsuccessful) I am tempted to post my answer and am having a friend verify it :)

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Suggestion: I think it could be even more informative by pointing out that this is _one notion_ of a time-energy uncertainty relation, and there are other notions too. The fact that there is more than one notion of this HUP comes from the the lack of a satisfactory time operator which would normally give a straightforward meaning and derivation.

Comment: @doublefelix, can you give us some references on that?

Comment: Check out "Time in the Quantum Theory and the Uncertainty Relation for Time and Energy" by Aharonov and Bohm (1961) for talk about the uncertainty relation. As for the time operator being a problem, I am aware of two "impossibility proofs". The most popular one is often called Pauli's Theorem, since Pauli wrote an early variant of it; I think you can google but also you can find a modern, improved, but more technical version of it in "The 'time of occurrence' in quantum mechanics" by Srinivas (1981), Pramana, Vol. 16, pgs 173-199.

Comment: The second "impossibility proof" is by Allcock in this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491669902516 , on the page numbered 264, paragraph starting with "the reader may object". It shows even more generally that there seems to be a problem with even a set of orthonormal time eigenfunctions, which rules out a time operator and more. Last time I read the proof I doubted one of the steps, involving expanding $\psi$ in only positive-momentum eigenstates, but it's likely that I missed something.

Answer (score 17):

The **time-energy uncertainty relation** (and other time-"observable" uncertainty relations that can be constructed) is (considered) not to have same meaning as **canonical uncertainty relations**. Meaning uncertainty relations costructed from canonical dynamical variables/observables (in the Hamiltonian sense), like position and momentum, since **time parameter** is **not an observable** and also **not an operator** in QM/QFT formalisms.

In fact, there are various approaches and interpretations of time-energy uncertainty. For example:

1. Energy-dispersion ($\Delta E$) of a state and lifetime ($\Delta t$ or $\tau_s$) of the state itself.
2. Energy exchange ($\Delta E$) and time-frame ($\Delta t$) during which this can happen.
3. Energy measurement ($\Delta E$) and time  ($\Delta t$) it needs for accuracy (although this is rigorously disputed, see below )
4. ..other similar or specialised formulations of the above

In L. Mandelstam and I. Tamm, "The uncertainty relation between energy and time in nonrelativistic quantum mechanics", J Phys (USSR) 1945, they show how one can derive time-observable uncertainty relations for any observable $A$ with

$$\Delta t = \tau_A = \frac{\Delta A}{d\left<A\right> /dt}$$

Time and time-energy uncertainty is used heavily in (quantum/mixed) statistical mechanics of systems since it relates half-times and life-times of states and transitions (will have to find some references)

An analysis of various formulations of time-energy uncertainty relations can be found in:

[Jan Hilgevoord, The uncertainty principle for energy and time I](http://www.phy.pku.edu.cn/~qhcao/resources/class/QM_panel_13/ajp_uncert_energy_time1.pdf)

and

[Jan Hilgevoord, The uncertainty principle for energy and time II](http://www.phy.pku.edu.cn/~qhcao/resources/class/QM_panel_13/ajp_uncert_energy_time2.pdf)

Summary:

> The uncertainty principle for energy and time is not a canonical
>   uncertainty relation because it is not based/produced by canonical
>   hamiltonian variables, instead it expresses dispersion and lifetime of
>   a state. There is a confusion of a cartesian space-time $x, t$ (used
>   as parameters) and canonical position and momenta ($q, p$) which are
>   functions of these parameters (however simple in some cases, like
>   $q=x$)

Answer (score 11):

The time-energy uncertaintly relation has a different interpration and derivation than the uncertaintly relation for non-commuting operators. Try [John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/uncertainty.html) for an explanation, but, roughly speaking $\delta t$ measures the time it takes for the expectation value of some operator to change noticeably.

Comment: The link is useful, but this is basically a link-only answer. Joshphysics' answer has given a self-contained presentation of the content of Baez's page.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Joshphysics' precise answer, let's mention another interpretation (the one I think Ben Crowell is referring to in his comment to the same answer).

There's a formula from time dependent perturbation theory which gives the probability of an induced transition from an initial state $\lvert i \rangle$ to a final state $\lvert f \rangle$ with energy difference $\hbar \omega_{if}$. The transition is supposed to be induced from an harmonic perturbation: $$V=\cal Ve^{i\omega t}+\cal V ^\dagger e^{-i\omega t},$$ and the formula reads, for absorption i.e. transition to an higher energy level:$$P_{i\to f}(t;\omega)=\dfrac{\lvert \cal V _{fi} \rvert ^2}{\hbar ^2}\dfrac{\sin ^2(\frac{\omega _{fi}-\omega}{2}t)}{(\frac{\omega _{fi}-\omega}{2})^2}.$$

As a function of $t$ for fixed $\omega$, the probability grows quadratically for small $t$, reaches its maximum at $t$ given by:$$\frac{\lvert \omega _{fi}-\omega \rvert}{2}t=\frac {\pi} {2},$$
that is: $$t\Delta E =\frac {h}{2},$$where $$\Delta E = \lvert E_f -E_i -\hbar \omega \rvert.$$

Suppose that I am trying to cause a transition beetween two energy levels $i,f$ of an atom by sending on it some radiation at frequency $\omega$. Then $\Delta t$ is the order of the required lenght of the interaction to have a consistent probability of a transition (note that the above formula for $P_{i\to f}$ makes sense at $t=t_{\text{max}}$ only if $|V _{fi}|\ll \Delta E$).

Instead of fixing $\omega$, we could imagine to fix the time of interaction $\Delta t$. Again, the above formula for $P_{i\to f}$ says that we have a consistent probability for the transition to occur if $\Delta E \ll \frac{h} {\Delta t}$. Therefore, if we wish to determine $E_f -E_i$ precisely enough by varying $\omega$ and seeing if the transition does or does not occur, we must have a big $\Delta t$.

Here I'm considering transition beetween two distinct levels and I'm assuming that the spectrum is discrete, in the physical sense, that is, $|E_f'-E_i-(E_f-E_i)|$ for every other level $f'$ is much bigger than the experimental uncertainty on $\hbar \omega$. If this was not the case, we should consider transition not to a single final state but to a group $[f]$ of final states. The correct way to do this is by Fermi's golden rule, which is discussed in every good book of quantum mechanics (see e.g. [Sakurai](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201539292) or [Griffiths](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131118927), also for the derivation of the above formula).

Answer (score 4):

Good answers have been given so far. Let us see it from a different perspective:

Think of two eletrons interacting with each other very briefly. This interaction takes place by means of energy exchage, and let us say this is an amount $\Delta E$. The time $\Delta T$ within which this energy must be exchanged between the two electrons has a limit, and is dictated by Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. The higher the amount of energy exchanged, the shorter the time it should take to exchange it. This is taken care by nature, the electrons just do what they have to do; they exchange energy 'folowing the rules.'

Similarly, a free photon carries an amount of energy $E=hf$. This also has the meaning of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle if you write it in the form $E\times T=h$, since $f=1/T$. This amount of energy, will be carried by the photon a distance of one wavelength, $\lambda =c/f$, in no longer or shorter time than the period of its probability wave. This also applies when we interact with nature durng a measurement, as has been mentioned by other respondens. Nature is very keen in optimising her action, she is not wasteful. A good question is: Why is $h$ as small as it is? What determines its value? I am not aware of any facility that will produce this number, other than measured experimentally.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is pretty much the same as for coordinate-momentum uncertainty. In addition to what joshphysics wrote, I'd like to stress that stationary solution of time-dependent Schroedinger equation is $\vert \psi \rangle \sim e^{i \frac{E}{\hbar}t}$. If you want to measure energy, you should somehow follow this wavefunction evolution in time. To measure energy definitely, you should measure it during infinite time. If the time of measurement is limited, the energy is not definite.

Technically it is more complicated as normally $\Delta t$ is not the measurement time, but the time of some process results of which you measure. However, the main idea is that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another interpretation of the relation $\Delta t \, \Delta E \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}$.

You have a classical system described by a lagrangian $L = \dot{q} \, p - H$, where $H$ is the hamiltonian which is supposed to be time independant.  The system's action is
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L \, dt = \int_{q_1}^{q_2} p \, dq - E \, \Delta t = S_p + S_E.
\end{equation}
Now consider an arbitrary variation of the classical path.  The action would then be changed by the following amount (I'm now sure what to do with the first part, which should give the other Heisenberg relation : $\Delta q \; \Delta p \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}$) :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\delta S_E = -\: \delta E \, \Delta t.
\end{equation}
***It is postulated that any variation that change the action by an amount less than $\frac{\hbar}{2}$ cannot be observable***.  This is similar to the minimal cell of phase space in statistical mechanics, for which $\Delta q_{\text{min}} \, \Delta p_{\text{min}} \sim h \equiv 2 \pi \hbar$.  Thus, for *observable processes* we have $|\, \delta S_E | \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}$, which implies the relation
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\Delta t \; \delta E \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}.
\end{equation}
Here, $\Delta t \equiv t_2 - t_1$ is just the time interval that defines the boundary of the action (1) above.  This is a classical "ordinary" interval of time.  $\delta E$ is the amount of energy variation that you could get relative to the classical value, during that time interval.  If $\Delta t$ is large, then $\delta E$ must be low (only small variations from the classical motion are allowed).

This "derivation" is very rough and is certainly not rigorous.

Comment: Your last statement is precisely what is excluded by the uncertainty relation. So it is not correct.

Answer (score -3):

In addition to what mentioned in @Michael's link, one of the best ways to think about is as follows:

The more time you spending in measuring your experiment (thus standard deviation will become smaller) the more precisely you will measure energy of this system.

P.S
This interpretation widely used in Russian text books.

Comment: sorry, I'm kind of confused by this interpretation. What exactly does it mean by spending more time measuring the experiment? In order to calculate the standard deviation, we need to measure the different possible results using identically prepared systems and figure out the corresponding probabilities.

Comment: While it is true that experiments dominated by statistical error see an improvement in precision over time, that improvement goes by $1/\sqrt{t}$, not by $1/t$ and in any case this is not down to any intrinsic effect of quantum mechanics. This is simply a incorrect way to interpret the uncertainty principle.