# Can we say there is literally nothing like vacuum

Tags: matter

OK am trying to find out the meaning of vacuum since particle do exist everywhere even where all 'matter' has being removed am certain the definition of vacuum doesn't make sense with particles can someone explain this better thanks in advance

Comment: Perfect vacuum would mean no particles at all. Locally, this is possible. On Earth as well as in space. Quantum field theory includes virtual particles though. At this point, the answer is not as clear

Comment: How did you conclude that particles are everywhere, even when all matter is removed?

Comment: @lmr virtual particles are not "particles" but quick-calculation tools.

Comment: I agree @Avantgarde but I've heard people argue that this makes a perfect vacuum Impossible. I mentioned it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @lmr I suppose a better way to state it would be that for a field $\phi$, the commutator $[\phi, \partial_t \phi] \neq 0$

Comment: No they are not just calculational tools, this is a very big misunderstanding with many budding scientists. The bigger majority of scientists will in fact tell you different and that virtual particles are in fact real. There are many reasons to think this is so.

Comment: I love the smell of vacuum in the morning!

Comment: Related: [Do virtual particles actually physically exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185110/123208), and the links there.

Comment: Related perhaps, but probably not best get swamped in a debate that possibly gives different interpretations. Best to go do an investigation and see what top physicists actually say about the matter.

Comment: Jmac, he is right. There resides fluctuations even when all the visible matter in a vacuum has been removed. This goes right back to zero point fields.