# Do empty space have momentum since uncertainty principle forbids 0 energy at any point?

Tags: momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, space

I like to know do vacuum space have momentum due to quantum fluctuations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There would be no direction for the vacuum expectation value of the momentum since all directions in a vacuum are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The **total momentum** at any point will be **zero** but as there are *minute fluctuations* in electric and magnetic fields, it can be stated that vacuum has momentum.

Do check out the existence of virtual particles. This might help you understand deeper about properties of vacuum

Comment: It's a little misleading to say that virtual particles exist. They *are* important, but they don't really exist in the way that non-virtual particles do. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185110/123208 & the links therein. OTOH, even the non-virtual particles are just a useful way to talk about the quantized excitations of quantum fields...