# Kinetic energy of quarks and mass of proton

Tags: mass, standard-model, mass-energy, quarks, protons

I read that:

> Most of a proton mass comes from the energy of motion of its three quarks and from the energy carried by the gluons that keeps them confined together.

Does kinetic energy of the three quarks in a proton contribute to the mass of a proton?  I assume the energy carried by the gluons is referring to the binding energy of the three quarks by the strong force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume the energy carried by the gluons is referring to the binding energy of the three quarks by the strong force.

It is more complicated than this. See how the strong interaction is figuratively modeled in terms of quantum field theory [in this article](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/)

[image: proton]

The invariant mass of the hadron is the [sum of the four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) of all those [virtual particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185110/do-virtual-particles-actually-physically-exist/185139#185139).

As the actual QFT function cannot be modeled because of the large coupling constant of the strong interaction, [QCD on the lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD) is used to model how the virtual three valence quarks and an innumerable number of quark antiquark and gluons add up to the hadronic bound states .  [example :](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.3483319)

[image]