# Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD) Prediction of Proton Mass

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, protons

I’m trying to understand the prediction of the proton mass according to Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD). I know that the proton is composed of quarks and gluons, and that the mass of the proton is not simply the sum of the masses of these constituent particles.

I’ve read that only about 1% of the proton’s mass comes from the mass of the quarks (which their mass comes from interaction with the Higgs field), and the rest comes from the energy of the quarks and gluons inside the proton, as well as quantum effects. However, I’m having trouble finding a specific numerical prediction for the proton mass according to QCD.

Could someone please explain what the current QCD prediction for the proton mass is, and how this compares to the experimentally measured value? Any references to relevant research papers would also be appreciated.

Comment: A partial answer to your question (concerning the proton-neutron mass difference) can be found in my answer to a previous question:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721760

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131487/how-literally-should-you-take-the-higgs-boson-gives-other-particles-mass).

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics_binding_energy).

Comment: Make sure you appreciate the ab initio [lattice calculation](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1257050) of the neutron proton mass difference, [ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4088). Your 9% looks too high by a factor of 10. Surely you don't mean it.

Comment: [Yang et al 2018](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.212001), summarized [here](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v11/118).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Also https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.08677

Comment: Yes, I assume the doi also trivially leads anyone to the e-print coordinate, no? Google Scholar!

Comment: FWIW, Frank Wilczek has a nice introductory article on this, *The Origin of Mass*, at https://www.frankwilczek.com/core.html In the early days of QCD he didn't have modern lattice techniques, so his first crude estimate of the proton mass was rather low, and took many weeks of number-crunching on a Cray supercomputer.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for correcting me, I messed up the 9 MeV to 980 MeV ratio (which is 1%) with "9%". I also read some of your links, they were super helpful.