# What is the frequency of virtual photons between two charges?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, frequency

Lets say I have 2 charged particals near each other.
My understanding is that They exchange virtual photons.
Do the virtual photons have a defined frequency/energy?

If so, what affects this frequency?

Thanks for your help in advace!

Comment: Virtual photons are "virtual", as the name implies. They are not real photons, but just an artifact of perturbation theory.

Comment: see my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185110/do-virtual-particles-actually-physically-exist/185139#185139

Comment: in addition, photons do not have frequency but are conencted through their energy to the frequency the classical wave built up by the same energy zero mass photons, would have. As the virtual ones are off mass shell, there is no way to define frequency for them.