# Do virtual particles share the same property values with the normal particles?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, virtual-particles

For example does a virtual electron have the same characteristic intrinsic values like mass, charge, magnetic moment etc. as a normal stable electron? Or can these range wildly and not having specific values for the case of the virtual particles and if yes don't you think that the  term for example "virtual electron" is kinda of misleading?

How can for example a virtual particle ten times the mass of its normal stable counterpart be the same particle?

Wouldn't it be a less specific but nevertheless more correct description of these particles be the term virtual fermions in general or virtual bosons or virtual pairs without labeling them with a specific normal particle's name of the Standard Model of particles?

Comment: " same characteristic intrinsic values like, mass" by construction, mass is off shell for  virtual particles. My answer here may clarify this  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185110/do-virtual-particles-actually-physically-exist/185139#185139 .