# Energy-Time Uncertainty Principle and Photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, photons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Heisenberg's uncertainty principle states that:
$$
\Delta E \cdot \Delta t \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}
$$
It is clear that this has nothing to do with the accuracy of our measurements, but rather is a fundamental 'law' in the quantum world. Now, we also know that photons do not experience time because of the Lorentz transformation time dilation:
$$
\gamma t = \frac{t}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}} = \frac{t}{1-\frac{c^2}{c^2}} = \frac{t}{1-1} = \frac{t}{0} = \text{undefined}
$$
Is the uncertainty principle not relativistic? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of reasoning is this?  What, on your understanding, does the symbol $\Delta t$ represent in the energy-time uncertainty relation?  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/

Comment: A change in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is correct in that the relativistic (or lorentz-invariant) [time-energy uncertainty relation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/129960/44176) is a bit different (but still there is)

For example here is a pre-print [Lorentz-Invariant Time-Energy Uncertainty Relation for Relativistic Photon, arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0201113)

Abstract:

> The time-energy uncertainty relation is discussed for a relativistic
>   massless particle. The Lorentz-invariant uncertainty relation is
>   obtained between the root-mean-square energy deviation and the scatter
>   of registration time. The interconnection between this uncertainty
>   relation and its classical analogue is established.

Answer (score 2):

The relation says that it would take about $\Delta t$ time to measure the energy with an error of order $\Delta E$. $\Delta t$ is not the photon time, it is the time in the observer's (laboratory) frame of reference.