# What is the meaning of definite total energy of the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

David J. Griffiths in *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* asked:

> What's so great about separable solutions of time independent Schroedinger equation?

His answer was

> They are states of definite total energy [...] the *Hamiltonian* $H(x,p) = \left(\frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)\right)$

I don't get this.

Answer (score 4):

You have undoubtably heard about [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle):

$$ \Delta x \, \Delta p \ge \frac{\hbar}{2} $$

There is a corresponding [energy-time uncertainty principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=energy%20time%20uncertainty%20principle):

$$ \Delta E \, \Delta t \ge \frac{\hbar}{2} $$

The point about the separable wavefunctions is that they are time independant, which means that $\Delta t = \infty$ and therefore that $\Delta E = 0$. This is what Griffiths means by *definite energy*.

The above argument is rather handwaving, but if you read the part of Griffiths following the excerpt you quote he makes this rigorous. The energy uncertainty, $\Delta E$, is the standard deviation defined by:

$$ (\Delta E)^2 = \langle H^2 \rangle - \langle H \rangle^2 $$

Griffiths shows that this is equal to zero.

Comment: The interpretation of the $\Delta t$ in the "energy-time uncertainty principle" is a bit difficult, see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/50583). Also, I don't how this answers OP's question *why* definite energy is a desirable property.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: yes, I agree, and what Griffiths really means is $\langle H^2 \rangle - \langle H \rangle^2 = 0$. my aim is to give some intuitive understanding of why this is significant.