# Subsequent measurement of energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-measurements

I am interested in the subsequent measurement of energy, like assume the energy of the electron was measured to be $E_1$ and the wavefunction of the electron is described by a finite superposition of eigenfunction of energy. After the first measurement will the subsequent measurement have the same energy measurement which is $E_1$.

I think this question has been asked multiple times, but what I am confused about is that if all the subsequent measurement was of state $E_1$ that means that the uncertainty in energy is zero, which implies that the uncertainty in time measurement has to be infinite.

Comment: Thanks so it's like 0/0

Comment: For typical energy measurement. the time duration delta t is rather long. A macrospcopic time can be viewed as microscopic infinite time. Since the delta t is infinity, delta E can be quite accurated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic quantum mechanics- violation of the time-energy uncertainty principle by pure eigenstates of the infinite potential well?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/357541/basic-quantum-mechanics-violation-of-the-time-energy-uncertainty-principle-by-p)