# Why does the uncertainty principle imply that empty space is filled with energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, vacuum

I read from this [website](http://whystringtheory.com/toolbox/quantum-strings/) that the uncertainty principle implies that seemingly empty space is filled with energy, called vacuum energy .
The relevant equation I can think of is $$\Delta E\Delta t \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}.$$
Here, $\Delta E$ is  standard deviation of energy for a system in quantum state $|\psi \rangle$ and $\Delta t$ is the approximate amount of time it takes for the expectation value of energy to change by a standard deviation as the system evolves.

How is this related to the statement that empty space is filled with energy?

Comment: "that empty space is filled with energy"  is not correct. The HUP applies to results of measurements, to measure you need interactions ,i.e. supply energy.

Comment: @AnnaV Correct, but QFT the same issue pops up as zero point energy. In my opinion absent in a sufficiently careful formulation.

Comment: While some pop-sci sources appeal to the HUP to explain the QFT vacuum, that is layering hand-waving on imprecision on vagueness.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/474545/50583

Comment: @AnnaV Fair enough, but as far as I know the mainstream physics opinion is that there is a cosmological constant problem.

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but as I recall in A Brief History of Time it is implied that  a part of space having zero magnetic and electric field and zero time derivatives for those fields implies a violation of the uncertainty principle. Been a long time.