# Is this analysis contradictory with the $2$'nd measurment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, measurements

### Summary and Motivation

"The below idea is about making a mathematical statement on system $2$ which induces a measurement on system $1$ while $1+2$ obeys unitary evolution."

Basically, I'm modelling the measurement (occurring at time $t$) as an interaction and that I have some constraints based on the conditions before ($\tilde t^-$)and after ($\tilde t^+$)

### Introduction

There are $2$ systems $1$ and $2$. Let the Hamiltonian of system $1$ be $H_1$ and let it be in an energy eigenstate:

$$ \hat H_1|E_m \rangle = E_m |E_m \rangle $$

Now, a measurement is done (forcing the system to a momentum eigenstate):

$$ \hat p |p_j \rangle = p_j |p_j \rangle$$

This measurement must me induced by a another system (see here why I think so: [Energy cost of the measurement without perturbing the system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484271/energy-cost-of-the-measurement-without-perturbing-the-system) ). Let the Hamiltonian of this system be $H_2$. Let us express the net Hamiltonian as:

$$ \hat H_{net} = \hat H_1 + \hat H_2 + \hat H'_{\text{int}(1,2)}$$

Where, $H_{\text{int}(1,2)}$ is the interaction Hamiltonian between the systems. But let us consider another system before we proceed:

$$ \hat H_{\text{non-int}} = \hat  H_1 \otimes \hat 1  + \hat 1 \otimes \hat H_2 $$

where $\hat 1$ is the identity matrix. In the non-interacting case we have a separable wave function:

$$ |\psi_{\text{non-int}} \rangle = |\psi_1 \rangle \otimes |\psi_2 \rangle = |\psi_1 ,\psi_2  \rangle $$

where $|\psi_1 \rangle $ and $|\psi_2 \rangle$ are the wave functions of system $1$ and $2$, respectively.

> Now, I know something about the time-evolution of system $1$ and I
>   know the net system $1+2$ obeys unitarity. Hence, I should be able to
>   use this to say something about system $2$.

After doing some "calculations" I got the following equation (first-order strong summation condition):

$$ 0 = \sum_{\lambda '} \sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle \langle \psi_2|E'_{\lambda'} \rangle \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '}|\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle =\sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle  \langle \psi_{\text{non-int}} |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle$$

### Questions

Now let's say I want to perform a measurement on $| \psi_{net} \rangle$ does the above equation add an additional constraint? If so does it interfere with the usual measurement postulates (and how badly) $|\psi_{net} \rangle \to |\text{eigenstate}\rangle $ and the probability of the eigenstate is $|\langle \psi_{net} |\text{eigenstate} \rangle |^2$?  If it invalidates the model I'm curious to know what was the false assumption?

Also, the current order of logic is: $\text{Measurement in system $1$} \implies \text{first-order strong summation condition} $. Is the inverse true? $\text{first-order strong summation condition} \implies \text{Measurement in system $1$}$

### Calculations

To make contact with the interacting case we use perturbation theory (assume $H'_{12}$ is small, see detour to justify this assumption):

$$ \hat H_{net} = \hat H_{\text{non-int}} + \epsilon \hat H_{\text{int}(1,2)}$$

Using [perturbation theory (upto first order correction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#First_order_corrections) in the energy eigenstates:

$$ |\psi_{\text{net}-n} \rangle = |\psi^{(0)}_{\text{non-int}} \rangle + \epsilon |\psi^{(1)}_{\text{non-int}} \rangle = |\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle + \epsilon |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle  $$

Where:

$$ \left|\psi_n^{(1)}\right\rangle =\sum _{k\neq n}{\frac {\left\langle \psi^{(0)}_k\right|\hat H_{\text{int}(1,2)}  \left|\psi^{(0)}_n\right\rangle }{E_{n}^{(0)}-E_{k}^{(0)}}}\left|\psi^{(0)}_{k}\right\rangle $$

### Case $\tilde t^-$:

(When not mentioned the kets are at time $\tilde t^-$ where $\tilde t^- = t- \tilde \epsilon_-$ and  $\tilde t^+ = t + \tilde \epsilon_+$)

Let $\psi_\text{net}$ be in some superposition of energy eigenstates:

$$ | \psi_{net} \rangle = \sum_{n} c_n | \psi_{net-n} \rangle$$

Let, us assume the measurement was done at a time $t$. Hence,

$$  |\psi_1 (\tilde t^-)\rangle =| E_m \rangle$$

On the other hand, let system $2$ be in some superposition of energy eigenstates:

$$ |\psi_2  \rangle = \sum_{\lambda '} c_{\lambda '}' |E'_{\lambda '}  \rangle$$

Putting things together:

$$ | \psi_{net} (\tilde t^-) \rangle = \sum_{n} c_n | \psi_{net-n} (\tilde t^-) \rangle = \sum_{n} c_n (|\psi^{(0)}_{n} (\tilde t^-) \rangle + \epsilon |\psi^{(1)}_{n} (\tilde t^-) \rangle )$$

However, we know,

$$|\psi^{(0)}_{n} (\tilde t^-)\rangle =  |E_m , E'_{\lambda'} \rangle_{n(m,\lambda)}$$

where $n(m,\lambda)$ is a function which puts $\tilde E_n = E_m + E'_{\lambda '}$ ($\tilde E_n$ is the energy of the non-interacting Hamiltonian) in ascending order (ignoring degeneracy). Also, to relate coefficients by the below procedure:

$$ | \psi_{\text{non-int}} (\tilde t^-) \rangle = |\psi_1 , \psi_2  \rangle = \sum_{\lambda '} c_{\lambda '}' |E_m , E'_{\lambda '}  \rangle $$

But we can also throw light on:
$$ |\psi_{\text{net}-n} \rangle = |\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle + \epsilon |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle  \implies \sum_{\lambda '}  c'_{\lambda '} |\psi_{\text{net}-\lambda} \rangle = | \psi_{\text{non-int}} \rangle +\epsilon  \sum_{\lambda '}  c'_{\lambda '}|\psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '} \rangle $$

Taking the inner product with $ | \psi_{net}  \rangle = \sum_{n} c_n | \psi_{net-n} \rangle = \sum_{n} c_n (|\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle + \epsilon |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle )$ and the right side of the above equation:

$$ 0 = \epsilon (\sum_{n} c_n  \langle \psi_{\text{non-int}} |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle + (\sum_{\lambda '} \bar{c}'_{\lambda '} \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '}|) (\sum_{n} c_n |\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle )) +O(\epsilon^2) $$

Ignoring $\epsilon^2$:

$$ 0=\sum_{n} c_n  \langle \psi_{\text{non-int}} |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle + (\sum_{\lambda '} \bar{c}'_{\lambda '} \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '}|) (\sum_{n} c_n |\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle )$$

Let us write the above more generally:

$$ 0=\sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle  \langle \psi_{\text{non-int}} |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle + \sum_{\lambda '} 
 \sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle \langle  \psi_{\text{non-int}} |E_m,E'_{\lambda'} \rangle  \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '}|\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle $$

Let, the above equation be called the $\tilde t^-$ equation.

### Case $\tilde t^+$ :

(When not mentioned the kets are at time $\tilde t^+$)

After the measurement on system $1$:

$$ |\psi_1 (\tilde t^+)\rangle =| p_j \rangle = \sum_k \langle E_k | p_j \rangle |E_k \rangle $$

Let system $2$ be in some superposition of eigen-energies:

$$ |\psi_2  (\tilde t^+)\rangle = \sum_{\lambda '} d_{\lambda '}' |E'_{\lambda '}  \rangle =  \sum_\lambda'   \langle E'_{\lambda '} |\psi_2  \rangle |E'_{\lambda '}  \rangle  $$

Again, to relate coefficients by the below procedure:

$$ | \psi_{\text{non-int}} (\tilde t^+) \rangle = |\psi_1 , \psi_2  \rangle = \sum_k \sum_{\lambda '} \langle E_k | p_j \rangle  \langle E'_{\lambda '} |\psi_2  \rangle |E_k , E'_{\lambda '}  \rangle $$

Following the same route as last time from $|\psi_{\text{net}-n}(\tilde t^+) \rangle = |\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle + \epsilon |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle$:

$$   \sum_k \sum_{\lambda '} \langle E_k | p_j \rangle  \langle E'_{\lambda '} |\psi_2  \rangle |\psi_{\text{net}-\lambda'} \rangle = | \psi_{\text{non-int}} \rangle +\epsilon  \sum_k \sum_{\lambda '} \langle E_k | p_j \rangle  \langle E'_{\lambda '} |\psi_2  \rangle |\psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '} \rangle $$

Also:

$$|\psi_{\text{net}}(\tilde t^+) \rangle = \sum_n \langle \psi_{\text{net-n}} | \psi_{\text{net}} \rangle (|\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle + \epsilon |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle)$$

Taking the inner-product of the above $2$ equations and focusing on the $1$'st order $\epsilon$:
$$ 0 =    \sum_n  \sum_k \sum_{\lambda '} \langle p_j  | E_k \rangle  \langle \psi_2  | E'_{\lambda '}   \rangle \langle \psi_{\text{net-n}} | \psi_{\text{net}} \rangle \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '} | \psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle + \sum_n \langle \psi_{\text{net-n}} | \psi_{\text{net}} \rangle \langle \psi_{\text{non-int}}|\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle  $$

Let, the above equation be called the $\tilde t^+$ equation.

### Combining the $\tilde t^-$ and $\tilde t^+$ Cases:

We also know, that $\psi_{net} $ undergoes unitary evolution:

$$ | \psi_{net} (\tilde t^+)\rangle = U(\tilde t^+,\tilde t^-)|\psi_{net}  (\tilde t^-)\rangle= e^{\frac{-iH_{net}(\tilde t^+ - \tilde t^-}{\hbar})} |\psi_{net}  (\tilde t^-)\rangle$$

Let us go to the Heisenberg picture (the kets do not depend on time), we do so for a straight forward example (and leave the rest for the reader to work out):

$$ \langle \psi_{\text{net-n}} (\tilde t^+) | \psi_{\text{net}} (\tilde t^+) \rangle = \langle \psi_{\text{net-n}}| \underbrace{U^\dagger (\tilde t^+,t') U(\tilde t^+,t')}_{\hat 1}| \psi_{\text{net}}  \rangle =  \langle \psi_{\text{net-n}}|  \psi_{\text{net}}  \rangle$$

We do this for all the kets (remove the time dependence). Hence, writing the $t^+$ equation minus the $t^-$ equation:

$$ 0 =    \sum_n  \sum_k \sum_{\lambda '} \langle p_j  | E_k \rangle  \langle \psi_2  | E'_{\lambda '}   \rangle \langle \psi_{\text{net-n}} | \psi_{\text{net}} \rangle \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '} | \psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle + \sum_n \langle \psi_{\text{net-n}} | \psi_{\text{net}} \rangle \langle \psi_{\text{non-int}}|\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle -\sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle  \langle \psi_{\text{non-int}} |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle - \sum_{\lambda '} 
 \sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle \langle  \psi_{\text{non-int}} |E_m,E'_{\lambda'} \rangle  \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '}|\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle   $$

Cancelling the term $\sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle  \langle \psi_{\text{non-int}} |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle $:

$$ 0 =    \sum_n  \sum_k \sum_{\lambda '} \langle p_j  | E_k \rangle  \langle \psi_2  | E'_{\lambda '}   \rangle \langle \psi_{\text{net-n}} | \psi_{\text{net}} \rangle \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '} | \psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle - \sum_{\lambda '} 
 \sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle \langle  \psi_{\text{non-int}} |E_m,E'_{\lambda'} \rangle  \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '}|\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle   $$

Note: tracing back the calculations we notice: $\langle  \psi_{\text{non-int}} |E_m,E'_{\lambda'} \rangle  = \langle \psi_2 , E_m |E_m,E'_{\lambda'} \rangle = \langle \psi_2|E'_{\lambda'} \rangle$. Now taking the summation common:

$$ 0 = \Big(\sum_{\lambda '} \sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle \langle \psi_2|E'_{\lambda'} \rangle \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '}|\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle \Big) \Big(\sum_k \langle p_j  | E_k \rangle -1 \Big) $$

Obviously:

$$ 1 \neq \sum_k \langle p_j  | E_k \rangle$$

Hence,

$$ 0 = \sum_{\lambda '} \sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle \langle \psi_2|E'_{\lambda'} \rangle \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '}|\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle $$

Re-substituting this in the $\tilde t^-$ equation (without time dependency) we get:

$$ 0=\sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle  \langle \psi_{\text{non-int}} |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle $$

Let the above equations be known as the "first-order strong summation condition".

### Detour about $\epsilon$ and $\tilde \epsilon_\pm$

I would like to supplement why the perturbation approximation is a good one. 
Let's say we are in the Heisenberg picture and we want to know the time evolution an operator in system $1$. A natural question arises which time evolution to use $H_{net}$ or $H_{1}$?The answer is the time evolution is the same (approximately):

$$ \langle m| \hat O_1(t') | n \rangle = \langle m|e^{\frac{i H_1 t' }{\hbar}} \hat O_1 e^{\frac{-i H_1 t '}{\hbar}}| n \rangle = \langle m|e^{\frac{i (H_1 + H_2 + H'_{12}) t' }{\hbar}} \hat O_1 e^{\frac{-i (H_1 + H_2 + H'_{12}) t' }{\hbar}}| n \rangle$$

The above makes sense iff,

$$ \langle k |e^{\frac{-i  H'_{12} t' }{\hbar}}| l \rangle \to 1$$

with $t' \neq t$ (the time of the measurement $\tilde \epsilon_\pm \neq 0$) where  $|k \rangle$ and $| l \rangle $ can be any basis element.

Comment: I just glanced through the details but your idea seems related to [weak measurements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_measurement), where the ancilla would be your system 1. If that is the case, the theory is pretty much well established already - so what would be your question?

Comment: thank you so much for looking at a long post! I'm not sure if this part is also in the literature but I obtain a condition: $ 0 = \sum_{\lambda '} \sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle \langle \psi_2|E'_{\lambda'} \rangle \langle \psi^{(1)}_{\lambda '}|\psi^{(0)}_{n} \rangle =\sum_{n}  \langle \psi^{(0)}_{n}| \ \psi_{net} \rangle  \langle \psi_{\text{non-int}} |\psi^{(1)}_{n} \rangle$ ... My question is since constrains the net system's wavefunction ... How does that go with the usual measurment postulates ...

Comment: Also my line of reasoning is given a measurment happens this equation is true  ... Is the opposite true? Given the equation is a measurement is then guaranteed ...

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin Also you say "idea seems related to weak measurements" ... I'm not sure if it has to be a weak measurement ... I think this works for any system which undergoes unitary evolution after the measurment ... See detour (last section) ...

Comment: I am sorry but I do not have the skills to seriously review your analysis. Now for the sake of clarity I think it would be worth elaborating a little about what you are exactly asking on the conceptual level, before launching the fireworks of formulas :) For example, is there an actual measurement assumed somewhere, or is this supposed to be a model for the measurement process? Note that the justification you give for introducting your system 2 is problematic, because it relies on your previous question having received a positive answer, which is not the case as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well, I assume a measurement happens at time $t$. A measurement is assumed which gives the formula (though as I said before I wonder if the opposite is true?) ... I agree but I suspect the reason is more that it's hard to find a counter example(/argument) to the other question (and being like the average physicist that I am ... that suffices for me) :P