# Wrong formulation of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

My professor wrote this on the blackboard:

$$\Delta E\Delta t \leq \hbar$$

Isn't the $\leq$ sign wrong? Or is this "another" possible formulation of [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)?

I am at the very beginning of quantum mechanics, so I am basically not aware of anything-ish. Except for the fact that every note and book I have read so far, mention the principle with $\geq$, no matter if $\Delta E \Delta t$ or with $\Delta x \Delta p$.

Comment: Yes, I think that your professor made a simple typo.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/36194 as to the interpretation since $t$ is not an observable in QM.

Comment: What reason did the professor give for this inequality, did the reason make sense to you, and if not, what is the conceptual issue that's troubling you?   If the professor had written the name of the course as PHSYICS 101, would you be posting to ask if this is a typo, or would you be figuring this out for yourself?

Comment: @WillO well said.  A simple search would turn up the correct inequality so unless there is some special context to write it wrong it takes all of 2 minutes to realize it’s a typo.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it arises from a simple typo in a particular source and is unlikely to be useful to future users.

Comment: Ask professor what he meant. This inequality is not very meaningful without explaining what $\Delta t$ is; $\Delta E$ is presumably uncertainty in energy $E$, but time coordinate $t$ usually does not have uncertainty in QT, it is treated as independent variable/parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't be confused. It is definitely $$\Delta E \Delta t \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$.

Your professor typo'd here, as if what he wrote: Then we could measure energy with any arbitrarily small error. We want to break the uncertainty principle and quantum mechanics, so it is $\geq$. We don’t want the error to be smaller than something, so it must be $\geq$, not $\leq$.