# Energy-time uncertainty for system with one eigenstate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I have been taking classes in theoretical physics and naturally been studying the heisenbergs uncertanty principle. So far the position-momentum kinda makes sense, but I can’t wrap my head around the energy-time uncertainty relation. Here is my problem:

Suppose you construct a potential and a wave function with only one eigenstate and thus only one defined energy. Then the energy uncertainty would have to be zero, but that would violate the energy-time uncertainty principle. Does that mean that the time uncertainty is infinite, and thus that you can’t measure the energy. Or does that imply that its impossible to construct a system with only one eigenstate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is $\Delta t$ in the time-energy uncertainty principle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/)

Comment: if the operator has only one eigenstate and eigenvalue then the operator is a scalar multiplier, there cannot be any *evolution* of it and the Mandelstam interpretation is not operative.

Comment: @hyportnex you should transform this into an answer.

Comment: such systems certainly exist: the deuteron for instance has a single bound state.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the difficulty is that $\Delta t$ is not generally well defined.  When writing $\Delta E\Delta t$, both terms are meant to be related to variance of operators.  However, time is not an operator in quantum mechanics so, as proposed by Mandelstam and discussed in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/36194), one often defines
$$
\Delta t= \frac{\sigma_A}{\vert d\langle A\rangle/ dt\rangle\vert}\,  .\tag{1}
$$
If there is only one bound state, then $\langle A\rangle $ cannot depend on $t$ because
$$
\langle \Psi(t)\vert \hat A\vert \Psi(t)\rangle=
\langle \psi\vert\hat A\vert\psi\rangle
$$
for $\vert\Psi(t)\rangle=e^{iEt/\hbar}\vert\psi\rangle$.

Thus, for any observable $d\langle A\rangle/dt=0$; in Eq.(1), one can understand $\Delta t\to\infty$ "in the physics way" (assuming $\sigma_A\ne 0$, whatever that means in such a system). You can then qualitatively salvage $\Delta E\Delta t$ by suggesting that $0\times \infty\ge \hbar/2$.

In practice, in a system with only one bound state, there is no natural time scale.  You cannot (for instance) define a unit of time based the energy of some transitions because your one bound state cannot transition to any other (bound) state.  Thus, the meaning of $\Delta t$ is poorly defined, and one must take great care in interpretation of $\Delta E\Delta t$.