# Why do the operators on either side of Schrodinger's equation show different hermitivity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

Schrödinger's Equation states that:
$$i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi(x,t)}{\partial t}=H \psi(x,t).$$

Now the Hamiltonian operator, $H$ is hermitian as long as the potential $V(x)$ is a real valued function of position only. And when $V(x)$ becomes a complex valued function, or depends on $\hat p$, $H$ is no longer hermitian.

But, on the other hand, $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is anti-hermitian throughout, as $i$ is anti-hermitian and $t$ is a parameter only.

Why is it that $2$ operators on two sides of an equation, $H$ and $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ performing similar operations on $\psi$ but exhibiting different hermitian behaviour? This happens to go against my intuition.

Is this thing normal by any means?

Correct me if I am wrong in my argument.

Comment: $\partial_t$ is **not** an operator in the Hilbert space, differently from $H$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti That looks like it should be an answer

Comment: Yes, but I do not have time to elaborate it. Furthermore I am sure that there is an explicit technical answer of mine on the same subject...

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112828/

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thanks for the answer!! I checked the answer in the link. It helped a lot. I will now try to find a bit more about $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ not being an operator in Hilbert space.