# Forbidden translation generators due to a finite radius of convergence of $\psi(x)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

In Quantum Mechanics, a translation by a distance $a$ is given by $\hat T(a)$-

$$\hat T(a) \psi(x)=\psi(x-a)$$
which shifts the graph towards the right by a distance $a$.

When we want to find the explicit form of the above transformation, we expand $\psi(x-a)$ in a Taylor series about the point $x$-

$$\psi(x-a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-a)^n}{n!}\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}\ \psi(x)$$

Using the fact that $\hat p\equiv-i\hbar\dfrac{d}{dx}$, we get-

$$\psi(x-a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-ia/\hbar)^n}{n!} \hat p^n\ \psi(x)$$

We see that RHS is the definition of- $\exp \Big(\dfrac{-ia\hat p}{\hbar}\Big) \psi(x)$

and thus we conclude $\hat T(a) \equiv\exp \Big(\dfrac{-ia\hat p}{\hbar}\Big)$

My doubt is that: In general the radius of convergence of any function in a Taylor series expansion about a point is *finite*, so the above proof tells us that $|a|$ can not be arbitrarily large. Why then, do we keep using the above generator for *any* value of $a$. My guess is that for well behaved functions, which $\psi$s obviously are, the radius of convergence is almost always large enough to talk about a sensible taylor series approximation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [Stone's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups)

Comment: Also, even considering only smooth wavefunctions is *not* enough for their Taylor series to have a non-zero convergence radius;

Answer (score 3):

One could argue that you're going about this backwards, if you want an *explicit* definition of $T_a$.  The definition
$$\big(T_a\psi\big)(x)= \psi(x-a)$$ is about as explicit a definition of an operator as you could ever hope for.  From there, we can define its infinitesimal generator $\hat p$ via
$$\hat p\psi = \lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \left[i\hbar\left(\frac{T_a - \mathbb I}{a}\right) \right]\psi = -i\hbar \psi'$$
whose domain consists of all functions $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that the aforementioned limit exists.

In fact, the expression $T_a = e^{-ia\hat p/\hbar}$ is *not* defined via Taylor series, but rather via the spectral theorem.  In broad strokes, the spectral theorem says that there is a unitary operator $U$ such that $U\hat p \psi = \hat \mu U \psi \iff \hat p = U^\dagger \hat \mu U$ where $\mu$ is a multiplication operator.  From there, one defines $e^{-ia\hat p/\hbar}:= U^\dagger e^{-ia\hat \mu/\hbar} U$.

---

In concrete terms for $\hat p$, differentiation is the same as Fourier transforming $\psi(x) \mapsto \tilde \psi(k)$, multiplying by $ik$, and then transforming back:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \psi(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{ikx} \tilde \psi(k)  dk = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{ikx} \bigg(ik \tilde \psi(x)\bigg) dk$$

so $U$ is the Fourier transform operator and $\mu: \tilde \psi(k) \mapsto \hbar k \tilde \psi(k)$ simply multiplies by $\hbar k$.  As a result, the **definition** of $e^{-ia\hat p/\hbar}$ is given by Fourier transforming $\psi(x)\mapsto \tilde \psi(k)$, multiplying by $e^{-ia(\hbar k)/\hbar}$, and then transforming back:

$$\bigg(e^{-ia\hat p/\hbar} \psi\bigg)(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int e^{ikx} \bigg( e^{-iak}\tilde \psi(k)\bigg) dk = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int e^{ik(x-a)} \tilde \psi(k) dk = \psi(x-a)$$

for all functions $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Why did you define momentum as the translation generator?

Comment: @IndischerPhysiker I didn't actually use the word momentum anywhere; $\hat p = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$ is the infinitesimal generator of spatial translations by definition.  The momentum operator is **defined** to be the generator of spatial translations because in Hamiltonian mechanics the momentum *observable* generates spatial translations (see e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/560303/156895)) and want to impose the same algebraic structure on our quantum theory. There are other ways to think about it [...]

Comment: [...] but this answer was written to explain how the right-hand side of $T_a := e^{-a \frac{d}{dx}}$ acts on non-analytic functions.

Comment: Okay, so does that *prove* that wave functions have an infinite radius of convergence?

Comment: @IndischerPhysiker No.  Almost *no* functions in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ are everywhere analytic. If you define $e^{-a\frac{d}{dx}}$ to be a shorthand for the Taylor series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-a)^n}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}$, then it's true that you'd need $\psi$ to be everywhere analytic in general; however, this is explicitly **not** how that expression is defined, as I mentioned in my answer. Defining it via the spectral theorem requires only that $\psi$ have a well-defined Fourier transform, which is true for all functions in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result in another way which doesn't assume an infinite radius of convergence. All we need is that for *infinitesimal* $\delta a$,
\begin{equation}
\psi(x - \delta a) = \left [ 1 - \frac{i \delta a}{\hbar} \hat{p} \right ] \psi(x).
\end{equation}
In other words, the first two terms of the Taylor series. Now, a way to make $\delta a$ arbitrarily small is to set it equal to a finite value $a$ divided by a number $N$ which is going to infinity.
\begin{equation}
\delta a \equiv a / N
\end{equation}
Then we use the fact that translations form an abelian group so shifting by $a$ is the same as shifting $N$ times by $\delta a$. As such,
\begin{align}
\psi(x - a) &= \psi(x - N \delta a) \\
&= \left [ 1 - \frac{i \delta a}{\hbar} \hat{p} \right ]^N \psi(x) \\
&= \left [ 1 - \frac{i a}{N \hbar} \hat{p} \right ]^N \psi(x).
\end{align}
If we now take the limit as $N \to \infty$, the definition of the exponential function nicely turns this into $\exp \left ( \frac{-ia \hat{p}}{\hbar} \right )$.