# Does the Schrodinger equation obey the rule for differentiating a function if the function is in terms of the wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

Does the Hamiltonian operator act like a derivative when acting on a functional in terms of wavefunctions?
For example, does $$H\psi^2=2\psi H\psi$$ hold true? More generally, if the functional, $F(\cdot),$ is solely in terms of the wavefunction, $\psi$, then does $$HF(\psi)=F'(\psi)H\psi?$$ If not, then why not?

Comment: Have you tried checking whether the first equation is true for the Hamiltonian of, say, a harmonic oscillator?

Comment: Do what  @G. Smith suggested, or even for a free particle

Comment: I can't imagine that such a thing will ever be relevant to you, because an expression like $H\psi^2$ is not even defined. $H$ acts on a vector $\psi$ and gives you another vector. But vectors do not act on each other so $\psi\psi$ has no clear meaning and it's certainly not something that $H$ can act on.

Comment: According to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17477/why-cant-i-hbar-frac-partial-partial-t-be-considered-the-hamiltonian-ope, the Hamiltonian acts on the wavefunction, not on general state kets. This means that $H\psi^2$ could be rigorously defined. You are taking the wavefunction as components and combining them into a vector while the question is about the components, not the vector...

Comment: The wave function is a general state ket.

Comment: You can construct some function by squaring the numerical values of the wave function in some basis and then apply a differential operator to that function but that doesn’t have any physical meaning in terms of your original system. You couldn’t interpret that as the Hamiltonian acting on anything.

Comment: If $\psi$ where an egienfunction of $H$ with eigenvalue $E$ then the result $H \psi^2 = 2 \psi H \psi$ would mean that $\psi^2$ was also an eigenfunction. with eigenvalue $ 2 E$. This is not true in general.

Answer (score 0):

Before providing an answer, I first want to provide some clarifications on the use of terminology. If the Hamiltonian is an operators (as we find in quantum mechanics) then what it operates on is usually referred to as a *state vectors* (or just *state*) and it is commonly represented in terms of Dirac notation by $|\psi\rangle$. A $wave function$ is obtained from such a state vector with the aid of a specific set of basis vectors. For the position basis, we have
$$ \psi(x) = \langle x|\psi\rangle , $$
and for the momentum basis (spatial Fourier basis) we have
$$ \psi(k) = \langle k|\psi\rangle . $$
The Hamiltonian operator cannot operate on these wave functions, because they are just c-number quantities. Hence, I assume that the question meant to ask about (tensor) products of state vectors, rather than products of wave functions.

To address the question we first ask how do we treat the situation where the Hamiltonian operator is applied to a tensor product of two state vectors
$$ |\psi\rangle = |\psi_1\rangle\otimes|\psi_2\rangle ? $$
Such a situation would for instance occur for two particles. One can express such a state as
$$ |\psi\rangle = \hat{a}_1^{\dagger} \hat{a}_2^{\dagger} |vac\rangle , $$
where
$$ \hat{a}_{1,2}^{\dagger} = \int \hat{a}^{\dagger}(k) \psi_{1,2}(k) dk , $$
with $\psi_{1,2}(k)$ being the Fourier domain wave functions. Since the Hamiltonian operators can also be expressed in terms of $\hat{a}^{\dagger}(k)$ one can now apply the Hamiltonian to tensor product state to see how it work. Indeed, we find that for a product of operators, the Hamiltonian operation follows a product rule, similar to the way it does for differentiations. This is because of the identity
$$ [\hat{A},\hat{B}\hat{C}] = [\hat{A},\hat{B}]\hat{C} + \hat{B}[\hat{A},\hat{C}] . $$

Now we can consider the case where the state is represented by some holonomic function of the creation operators. Say
$$ |\psi\rangle = F\left(\hat{a}_1^{\dagger}\right) |vac\rangle , $$
where
$$ F(x) = \sum_m C_m x^m , $$
with $x\rightarrow \hat{a}_1^{\dagger}$. Such a situation is found in coherent states, for instance. When the Hamiltonian is now applied to this state, which we can evaluate for each term in the expansion, we find a result similar to the chain rule for differentiations.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I don't think this is consistent with what OP wrote (but what OP wrote isn't well defined). You are thinking of the case where the theory has a Fock space and $H$ is the Hamiltonian on that Fock space. But then OP writes $\psi H \psi$ which in your notation would be $|\psi\rangle\otimes H|\psi\rangle$, but now this $H$ is something that only acts on the 1-particle subspace of the Fock space, so it's not really the same thing.

Comment: Note the factor of 2 in the OP's expression. In my notation it means $|\psi_1\rangle\otimes H|\psi_2\rangle+|\psi_2\rangle\otimes H|\psi_1\rangle$. So, I think it comes down to the same thing.

Comment: I wasn't worried about the 2. My point is that it seems like the $H$ in the LHS is an operator on the *full* Hilbert space, whereas the $H$ in the RHS seems to be an operator on the *1-particle sector*. I feel like sloppy notation here is obscuring the fact that this is all inconsistent.

Comment: The notation is indeed a problem. However, I think the question of the OP specifically deals with whether one can treat the Hamiltonian which is defined for the whole Hilbert space on individual particles, one at a time, and the answer is yes. One can see that by explicitly writing it out in terms of ladder operators.

Comment: Sorry to be technical, but that's not true, unless I've misunderstood you. I think you may possibly be confusing $|\psi\rangle\otimes|0\rangle$ with $|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: That is not what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 1D hamiltionian of the form $H = p_x^2/ 2 m + V ( x )$ then $H \psi^2$ would look like
$$ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{d x^2} \psi^2 + V ( x ) \psi^2,$$
and you would have
$$\frac{d}{d x} \psi^2 = 2 \psi \frac{d \psi}{d x}$$
so that
$$\frac{d^2}{d x^2} \psi^2 = 2 \frac{d}{d x}\left( \psi \frac{d \psi}{d x} \right) = 2 \left( \frac{d \psi}{d x} \right)^2 + 2 \psi \frac{d^2 \psi}{d x^2}.$$
There is an extra term involving $\left( \frac{d \psi}{d x} \right)^2$ that messes up your initial suggestion.