# Energy Operator, Hamiltonian, Energy Eigenvalues

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

Can we use the energy operator $i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ instead of the Hamiltonian to obtain the energy eigenvalues?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17477/2451